# How to use the FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, fft

I'm just learning Matlab and the fast fourier transform algorithm.

As a first step I tried to duplicate this example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Example

I use the following code:

```
t = -6:0.01:6;
s = cos(2 * pi * 3 * t) .* exp(-pi * t.^2);
figure(1);
plot(t, s);
xlim([-2 2]);
r = fft(s);
figure(2);
plot(t, abs(r));
```

And I obtained the following picture:

**Figure 2:**

[image: Figure 2]

Figure 1 is OK, but Figure 2 is not. I see one of the problem is that in Figure 2 I should plot vector r *against* frequency, not against time. Another problem in Figure 2 is the scale in the Y-axis.

Thus, I have 2 questions in order to duplicate the example:

1. How can I obtain the frequency domain (X-axis in Figure 2)?
2. How should I scale vector r (Y-axis in Figure 2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you aren't actually creating a frequency vector to plot the `fft` against. The reason that the fft is plotted against time is because that is what you specified in your plot command.

Here is a working fft outline:

```
N=length(t);
index=0:N-1;
FrequencyResolution=SamplingRate/N;
Frequency=index.*FrequencyResolution;
data_fft=fft(detrend(data)); 
%the detrend isn't necessary but it does look nicer because it focuses the plot on changes around the mean of the data
data_FFTmagnitude=abs(data_fft);
plot(Frequency, data_FFTmagnitude)
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember once for the first time that I wanted to use DFT and FFT for one of my study projects I used this [webpage](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html), it explains in detail with examples on how to do so. I suggest you go through it and try to replicate for your case, doing so will give you insight and better understanding of the way one can use FFt as you said you are new to Matlab. Do not hesitate to ask again if you need more detailed help.

And also keep in mind that for FFT it is better to have signal length of a power of 2, that way you will get the most exact results, and if you cannot control your signal length you can take the largest power of 2 close to that length, as everyone usually does.

Comment: This isn't completely germane to the question, but the reason for having signal lengths or transform sizes that are powers of 2 isn't about accuracy of results (no practical FFT will be exact anyway), it's about speed.  Transform sizes with small prime factors run faster because the problem can be subdivided more easily.

Comment: @CKT I never said that signal length is the issue, it was just a suggestion for him/her as a starter. Speed is true, but the accuracy of the frequency resolving is directly affected by taking power 2 signal length, this is the case for FFT not DFT, you can try yourself and see.

Comment: Yes, you can try for yourself:

>> DFT = @(N) exp(-1j*2*pi/N*(0:(N-1))'*(0:(N-1)));
>> x = randn(100,1);
>> max(abs(DFT(100)*x-fft(x))./abs(DFT(100)*x))
ans =
   1.3516e-13
>> x = [x; zeros(28,1)];
>> max(abs(DFT(128)*x-fft(x))./abs(DFT(128)*x))
ans =
   1.5653e-13

So, no, not having a power of 2 isn't necessarily going to give you worse accuracy.  People don't use powers of 2 in the FFT for accuracy, they use it for speed.  In general, you're not going to get any worse accuracy for non-power-of-2 sizes.  The exp(__) terms won't give you any better roundoff when N is a power of 2.